# How to add metadata (or extra field) into WebRTC MediaStreamTrack for remotes?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Local peer may add camera track and screen track:

```
pc.addTrack(cameraTrack, stream);

// I want do something like: 
// screenTrack.setField('isScreen', true);
pc.addTrack(screenTrack, stream);
```

Remote peer receives track event:

```
pc.ontrack = function(evt){
    if (evt.track.getField('isScreen') == true){
      // do something for the screen track
    }
    else {
      // do something for the user camera
    }
}
```

The question is: how can the remote peer aware of the different track, since the local peer may send in different order?
Is is possible for local user do something like `cameraTrack.addMetaData('type', 'camera')` or `screenTrack.setField('isScreen', true)`? 
Basically, how to tell extra metadata for track information to remote peers?

Comment: Couldn't you send this info manually through an [RTCDataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel)?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, but it seems createDataChannel will renegotiate and generate SDP offer answer, which I do not want to happen.